# Can't hide group box in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm learning GUI programming with qt. I have a problem with Shape-Changing Dialogs. Like this:
[image]

To do so, I added some signal-slot, like `connect(ui->pbMore,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),ui->gbSecond,SLOT(setShown(bool)));` but it ain't work. I tried `setVisible(bool)` or set the connection on the GUI but no luck either.

This is an example from the book C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, Second Edition. They do the same way with me. So what's my mistake?

Edit: add ui file and codes.

dialogexpand.h

```
#ifndef DIALOGEXPAND_H
#define DIALOGEXPAND_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
    class DialogExpand;
}

class DialogExpand : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogExpand(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DialogExpand();

private:
    Ui::DialogExpand *ui;
public:
    void SortDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setColumnRange(QChar first, QChar last);
};
```

dialogexpand.cpp

```
#include "dialogexpand.h"
#include "ui_dialogexpand.h"

DialogExpand::DialogExpand(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogExpand)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);



    connect(ui->pbMore,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),ui->gSec,SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
    connect(ui->pbMore,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),ui->gbThird,SLOT(setShown(bool)));

//    ui->gbThird->hide();
//    ui->gSec->hide();
    SortDialog();
}

DialogExpand::~DialogExpand()
{
    delete ui;
}

void DialogExpand::SortDialog(QWidget *parent)
{

//         ui->gSec->hide();
//         ui->gbThird->hide();
         layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
         setColumnRange('A', 'Z');
}

void DialogExpand::setColumnRange(QChar first, QChar last)
{
    ui->cbFirstColumn->clear();
    ui->cbSecColumn->clear();
    ui->cbSecColumn_2->clear();
    ui->cbFirstColumn->addItem(tr("None"));
    ui->cbSecColumn->addItem(tr("None"));
    ui->cbFirstColumn->setMinimumSize(
                ui->cbSecColumn->sizeHint());
    QChar ch = first;
    while (ch <= last) {
        ui->cbFirstColumn->addItem(QString(ch));
        ui->cbSecColumn->addItem(QString(ch));
        ui->cbSecColumn_2->addItem(QString(ch));
        ch = ch.unicode() + 1;
    }
}
```

ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>DialogExpand</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="DialogExpand">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>354</width>
    <height>307</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="gbFirst">
     <property name="title">
      <string>&amp;Primary key</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lbColumn">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Column</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbFirstColumn">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>None</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>109</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lbOrder">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Order</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbSecColumn_2">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ascending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Descending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1" rowspan="2">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbOk">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&amp;OK</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbCancel">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&amp;Cancel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeType">
        <enum>QSizePolicy::Expanding</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>20</width>
         <height>13</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbMore">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&amp;More</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>59</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="gSec">
     <property name="title">
      <string>&amp;Sec key</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lbColumn_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Column</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbSecColumn">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>None</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lbOrder_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Order</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbSecOrder">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ascending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Descending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="0">
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="gbThird">
     <property name="title">
      <string>&amp;Teriatriy key</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lbColumn_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Column</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbThirdColumn">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>None</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="lbOrder_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Order</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbThirdOrder">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ascending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Descending</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>pbOk</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>DialogExpand</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>304</x>
     <y>22</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>268</x>
     <y>104</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>pbCancel</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>DialogExpand</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>324</x>
     <y>54</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>341</x>
     <y>111</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer: add `ui->pbMore->setCheckable(true);` did the trick

Credited to [Zlatomir](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/51981-Shape-Changing-Dialog?p=232708#post232708)